# Applescript : Lock & UnLock MacOS based on device stats

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to do a script to lock my computer when a USB key is not connected and the other way , unlock my computer when the USB is connected.

I'm not quite sure how to do the second part, should I just remove Password requirement for unlocking when the USB is connected?

```
property Disconnected : true
property MyShellScript : missing value

on YubiKeyConnected()

    try
        set MyShellScript to do shell script "ioreg -c IOUSBDevice | grep Yubikey"
    on error
        set MyShellScript to "Not Connected"
        set Disconnected to true
    end try

    if MyShellScript contains "Yubikey NEO OTP+U2F+CCID@10" then

        set Disconnected to false
    end if
end YubiKeyConnected


on idle
    set currentState to YubiKeyConnected()
    if MyShellScript contains "Yubikey NEO OTP+U2F+CCID@ 10" then


    else if Disconnected is true then
        activate application "ScreenSaverEngine"
    end if
    return 1
end idle
```

Update : I found this but keep having the error "error "security: SecKeychainSearchCopyNext: The specified item could not be found in the keychain." number 44"

```
tell application "System Events"
    if ((get name of every process) contains "ScreenSaverEngine") then
        set pw to (do shell script "security find-generic-password -l \"[MyLocalPassword]\" -w")
        tell application "ScreenSaverEngine" to quit
        delay 0.5
        keystroke pw
        keystroke return
        -- set require password to wake of security preferences to false
    end if
end tell
```

Answer (score 2):

delay 5

Can use this but not really secure :

tell application "System Events"
    if ((get name of every process) contains "ScreenSaverEngine") then
        set pw to "Password Here"
        tell application "ScreenSaverEngine" to quit
        delay 0.5
        keystroke pw
        keystroke return
        -- set require password to wake of security preferences to false
    end if
end tell